# URL does not process properly. What might be the reason?

Tags: jquery, html, jakarta-ee

I'm facing this weird issue. The following url is working fine on my machine. I mean the value for the data param is setting properly and once user click it goes to the relevant page but some how in one of my colleague machine it still remaining as  `/path4/'+data+'"` even the value for the data is coming properly.

We are using JQuery for the UI and app is running on tomcat v7.0.x and web browser is Google Chrome

Here is the URL with the Jquery function

```
function(data){
     return '<a class="edit tooltips" data-original-title="View"      
     href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/path1/path2/path3/path4/'+data+'">'
     + '<button class="btn_small tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original- 
     title="View">'
     + '<i class="icon-eye-open icon-white"></i>'
     + '</button>' + '</a>';
 }
```

do you guys have any idea about what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Newly edited question, new answer ...*

Seems like your function could use a name, but the body of the function looks ok.

Can you try removing line returns in case there's something weird going on there? When I copy/pasted into a fiddle I got a warning about an illegal character.

Comment: We were able to solve the issue by removing the ${pageContext.request.contextPath} from the URL and using the previously setted variable with the contextPath. but still wondering what might be the reason. Sometimes may be a tomcat version issue or browser version issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/path1/path2/path3/path4/"+data+"'">Click Here</a>
```